# Apt-file equivalent to Homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am looking for the name of a package that contains a specific file. I can easily do this in Debian system with `apt-file search` command, but I haven't found a way for brew packages on OSX. Any tool to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There’s currently no way to do that. If the file you’re looking for is an executable, you can check [`homebrew-command-not-found`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-command-not-found):

```
brew tap homebrew/command-not-found
```

Then use `brew which-formula <executable>` to get the formula that installs it:

```
$ brew which-formula python
python
$ brew which-formula aclocal
automake
```

(disclaimer: I’m the maintainer of `homebrew-command-not-found`)

Answer (score 0):

'brew info' will give information on the formula such as dependencies. Or ask the question [here](https://discourse.brew.sh/).